# Prove $\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$ is irrational

Tags: trigonometry, irrational-numbers

Prove that for every number $n\in\mathbb N$,number $\cos\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}$ is irrational.
I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Use half-angle formula for cosine.

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/douangl/douangl.html

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Apparently, for the OP, natural numbers start at $1$.

Comment: oh sorry missed that

Comment: directly read the question on the top

Comment: "I really don't know where to start": 1) don't you know particular values of $n$ such that the claim holds ? 2) do you know any formula that can be used for induction ?

Comment: Counterexample: $\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{0+1}} = 0$

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thank you for pointing that out. I'll try avoid skimming over things in the future. My preference would have been $n\in   \mathbb N^{+}$

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $\cos(\pi/2^{n+1})$ is irrational, but $\cos(\pi/2^{n+2})$ is rational; set $\alpha=\pi/2^{n+2}$; then $2\alpha=\pi/2^{n+1}$ and
$$
\cos2\alpha=2\cos^2\alpha-1
$$

Can you see the contradiction?

To finish, note that for $n=1$ we have $\cos(\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}/2$.

Comment: Let $S = \left\{n\ge 1 : \cos \dfrac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\in\mathbb Q\right\}$ Clearly $1 \not\in S$. Suppose that $S$ is not empty. Let $m$ be the smallest member of $S$. Then $\cos \dfrac{\pi}{2^{m+1}}\in\mathbb Q$ and
$\cos \dfrac{\pi}{2^{m}}\not\in\mathbb Q$ ...

Comment: it is a shorter proof that $\cos(\pi 2^{-m-1}$ is algebraic and $[\mathbb{Q}(\cos(\pi 2^{-m-1}):\mathbb{Q}] > 1$ i.e. that the minimal polynomial of $\cos(\pi 2^{-m-1})$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ has degree $ > 1$

Answer (score -2):

Proof by mathematic induction:

base case:

when $n = 1, \cos({\frac{\pi}{2^{n + 1}}}) = 2\sqrt{2}$ is clearly irrational

Now suppose when $n = k, \cos({\frac{\pi}{2^{k + 1}}})$ is irrational

When $n = k + 1$

\begin{align}
\cos({\frac{\pi}{2^{k + 2}}}) &=\cos({\frac{\pi}{2^{k + 1}}} \times\frac{1}{2})\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\cos({\frac{\pi}{2^{k + 1}}}) + 1}{2}}
\end{align}

$\because$ an irrational number plus a rational number is irrational, the constant multiple of irrational number is irrational, and power of irrational number is irrational

$\therefore$ when $n = k + 1$ the original proposal is true

$\therefore$ the statement is proved.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answer.

Comment: $2\sqrt2$ is not in the range of cosine